# Visual Studio 2010 introduces "No drag and drop customization of menus and toolbars"

Tags: visual-studio-2010, drag-and-drop, customization

What went wrong with the Microsoft Visual Studio team, for them to remove the drag-and-drop functionality of menu and toolbar customizations? You now are greeted with a friendly looking dialog box that lets you "Add" and "Remove" items using listboxes and other primitive means of customization.

How do I quickly customize items here? Or should I switch back to VS 2008?

Comment: Despite your question being a little argumentative you should consider the sheer amount of available commands in VS. Maybe for a not so frequent task such as customizing a menu or toolbar a structured dialog is not too bad after all. If that's annoying you too much you can always write your own add on, I suppose. And don't forget that VS 2010 has a completely written UI, so this feature has not been "removed", it simply hasn't been added yet, because there were probably other issues that received higher priority.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do miss this feature too. Here is what I like about it.
To save space I like to close most of the toolbars. So I create one of my own and drag all the commands I use to it. Better yet, I used to use the unused space on the menu bar to put my favorite buttons there. that way I were able to do away without toolbars. Vertical space is too precioius for me.

I also not entirely agree that it is a rare procedure. In a large project one has to wonder about other people desktops and the labs, so one is (depending on the industry of cause) might be exposed to the need to set up someone else's VS for one's needs.

I accept that one might need to wait until the MS team gets to implement this. I would breath easier if I knew they plan to.